# .htaccess - Add prefix string to beginning of URLs

Tags: php, regex

I'm migrating a website over to a new server and on the old server the website existed in the document root (/var/www/html/). The new server will contain multiple websites and so I put it in it's own directory (/var/www/html/dev.newsite.com).

The problem is that all of the links on the website were built based on the old document root. I'd like to not have to change the document root in the httpd.conf file. How can I prepend 'dev.newsite.com' to the beginning of all the URLs on my site using the .htaccess file? Thank you!

Comment: A better solution would be to use relative paths in your application

Comment: Also, investigate using vhosts for your various sites, so each site can have its own document root.

Comment: Jerry, this was the optimal solution. Thank you for your suggestion!